# How to hide label on radio checked using css

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox in label tag like this.

```
<label class="duck duck1">
  <input type="checkbox">
</label>
```

I want if i click on checkbox, label and checkbox both should be `display:none` without jquery.

I tried this.

```
.duck input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.checkbox  {display: none;}
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/cvnLfxtx/)**

Comment: it doesnt work the way you think it works. using css, you can only select an element that comes after the one you clicked, not before and not a parent. please consider using javascript for that purpose.

Comment: You mean its not possible with css.

Comment: It is possible if you change your structure like this `<input type="checkbox" /> <label class="duck duck1"></label>`

Comment: Yes, if he change the structure as @SureshPonnukalai suggests it can be done input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .duck{ display: none; }, otherwise there are no css selectors for parent :)

Comment: Your structure lacks a label (descriptive text, not the element) and for/id association between label and form field, as in `<label class="duck duck1" for="anId"><input type="checkbox" id="anId"> Duck</label>` (relevant WCAG 2.0 Techniques are [H44](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H44.html), [H65](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H65.html), [G131](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G131.html) and [F17](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F17.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, as i said before: using css, you can only select an element that comes after the one you clicked, not before and not a parent.

**you can work around that however. Have a look at the following code:**

if you reconstruct your html to have the label after the checkbox, and add the animated classes to the checkbox as well, to align it with the label:

```
<div class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" class="duck duck1 cb_1"></input>
    <label class="duck duck1"></label>
</div>
```

you will be able to select both in the following way:

```
input[type=checkbox].cb_1:checked,
input[type=checkbox].cb_1:checked + label {
    display: none;
}
```

here is a fixed <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/cvnLfxtx/3/)</kbd>

(the `.cb_1` class is only meant for the z-index to make checkbox appear above the lable, and to avoid other checkboxes on the page hide irrelevant labels)

**UPDATE:**

another workaround would be to create the label (or duck image sprite) using the `:after` pseudo selector:

```
.duck:after{
    content:'';
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute; 
}
```

here is an example with the `:after` selector: <kbd>**[Duck Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/cvnLfxtx/7/)**</kbd>